# showing validation error message like tooltip

Tags: jquery, css

how to show validation message  like the below shown images on a html form.

I tried in Web, but could not found like this validation. So though to ask you here, may be someone can help me with this.

I want to show valdation error message as shown in below image...

Please anyone help me...

[image]

---

OR LIKE  THIS BELOW IMAGE

---

[image]

Comment: [**Everyone loves Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Comment: wow, does that dotted green line mean that the validation message did a loop while flying into view.  That would be awesome.

Comment: And where is your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are trying for your own javascript and you are new to it , then It would take a quite a bit of learning as you should be aware with playing with DOM elements and knowing other DOM behaviors. A quick solution would be using Jquery Library and Jquery Validation Plugin. There are so many Jquery Form validator which makes the use of tooltip to display error.

Some of them are :

http://thrilleratplay.github.io/jquery-validation-bootstrap-tooltip/
http://jqueryvalidationunobtrusivenative.azurewebsites.net/AdvancedDemo/Tooltip
http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html
https://github.com/yairEO/validator
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Answer (score 3):

On error display I would do it like this:

- Set position relative to the parent of the field.
- Append an absolute positioned div next to the field (in the same parent as the field)
- Set left:100% or right:100% on the div
- Set the content of the div to the error message

Now if you compress those steps you would get an HTML structure like.

```
<div class="fieldWrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <input ....>
    <div class="errorMessage" style="position:absolute; left:100%;"> Error message </div>
</div>
```

If don't want to add the additional `"fieldWrapper" divs` you could set the top and left of the error message programmatically like this:

- Get the `offsetTop` of the field and the `offsetLeft`
- Add that offsets as the `top` and `left` value of the error message.